# Prevent Visual Studio 2013 from opening web app after publish

Tags: iis, web-applications, visual-studio-2013

Is there any possibility to prevent Visual Studio 2013 from opening my web application after I published them? I did not find anything on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a file containing your publish settings under `Properties/PublishProfiles` in your web application.

Open up the relevant `Publish Profile` for your target, and locate:

```
<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
```

Change that to `false` and that should do the trick.